# New kalanchoe is turning brown

Tags: kalanchoe, browning

I bought a Kalanchoe flower plant three days ago and have been monitoring its condition ever since. I noticed that *the tips of a lot of the blooming flowers and buds are turning brown*. Some edges of the leaves are also wilting progressively.

I don’t know much about plants, but I did some research and feel like I am meeting most of the plant’s requirements. I made sure it got as much bright, indirect sun as possible by placing next to a window, but I live in a cloudy and rainy city so it’s hard.

I also haven’t watered it since I got it back because I was told to feel how moist the dirt was, then decide if I should water it. The dirt in the pot has been quite moist and not dry. The only thing I did was put a single ice cube in and let it melt halfway.

Not sure if this messed things up. Any clues as to what might be going on? Or is this normal? Just wondering.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jennie, welcome to the site.  The flowers are not going to last forever.  Are you able to post a picture of a leaf of concern?

Comment: Succulents get cactus treatment ... dry and sunny. But the home is never going to be the greenhouse where the plant thrived. Plant looks fine.